# How to scroll a detached object?

Tags: jquery, html

Consider the following lines of jQuery:

```
var $s = $('<span><span class="one"><span class="two"></span></span></span>');

$('.one', $s).css('border', 'solid 1px black').scrollLeft(200);
$('.one', $s).css('border', 'solid 1px blue').scrollTop(200);

$(document.body).append($s);
```

Now I would like to do some scrolling **before** the elements are attached to the DOM (due to visual requirements), but the scrollbars remain at 0. **How can I scroll an element before it is attached to the DOM?**

<sub>JS Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/gQbkw/1/</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't scroll an element unless it is attached to the DOM because the browser has no knowledge of it's dimensions and if it can scroll or how much it can scroll by.

Answer (score 2):

1. add the element to the body with an absolute position
2. set the top and left to a place off the screen
3. scroll the elements
4. attach it to the correct place and remove the absolute positioning

Oh, and another thing, instead of setting the border using the css - put it in a class

**edit:** following your comment about IE here is a solution http://jsfiddle.net/gQbkw/4/
i used another div as container, this is a simplified solution, checked it in IE9 and chrome

Comment: In other words, you can't scroll an element unless it is attached to the DOM because the browser has no knowledge of it's dimensions and if it can scroll or how much it can scroll by.

Comment: Another attach will reset scrolling as well :( (IE)

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by using an element before adding it to the document.For resollving this, you need to add this element to the document first and then do an append operation on this element

```
var $spans = $('<span><span class="one"><span class="two"></span></span></span>');

$(document.body).append($spans);

$('.one', $spans).css('border', 'solid 1px black').scrollLeft(200);
$('.one', $spans).css('border', 'solid 1px blue').scrollTop(200);
```

Comment: That's by design. The question is if it is possible to do it without attaching it.